# How to make React functional component render sequential space characters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make the string rendered by a React functional component include more than one space character in sequence.

This is the function in my .js file:

```
function Square() {
  let output = "     |\n     |\n     |\n     |\n___________|"

  return(
    <div className="display-linebreak">
       {output}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the style rule in the .css file it imports:

```
.display-linebreak {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

And this is how it currently renders on the webpage:

```
|
|
|
|
___________|
```

I'm building a basic tic-tac-toe game with the board made up of simple characters, and this is the northwest square of the 3-by-3 grid, so all the pipe characters should be vertically aligned along the right edge.

I've read about and tried lots of things to render the extra space characters I need, using stuff like "template literals" or `&nbsp;`, but nothing that's worked for others in the examples on here seems to work for me with this.

These are the versions I'm using:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `<div>` with `<pre>` and using the exact same number of characters on line a should solve this:

```js
function Square() {
  let output = "           |\n           |\n           |\n           |\n___________|"

  return(
    <pre>
       {output}
    </pre>
  );
}
```

This will obviously work only when using a monospaced font, but that should be default for `<pre>` in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html `<pre></pre>` element.

```js
<div className="display-linebreak">
  <pre>
    {output}
  </pre>
</div>
```